# Pre-processing JavaScript with Node JS

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to intercept Node JS loading *.js files in order to pre-process them?

I want to be able to extend a standard JavaScript file with a special-syntax section that needs to be replaced with valid JavaScript on-the-fly as Node JS loads the file.

Or is there already a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to intercept Node JS loading *.js files in order to
>   pre-process them?

Why do you want to do so when files are being loaded?

Pre-processing should be done during build-time. Look for a task runner like [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), and implement that pre-processing during build-time and load processed files during run-time providing your own *build task*.

Comment: I would like very much not to rely on an additional setup, and do on-demand transformations.

Comment: @vitaly-t but your approach has performance implications. And about the setup, it might be a 10 lines of code setup, and since you're already using nodejs, there's nothing to install manually..

Comment: @vitaly-t I would say that you need to re-think your solution and go for the build-time approach... No one is pre-processing files on-demand........well, unless you're in development mode. For example, BabelJS can transpile ECMA-Script 6 into 5 during run-time, but once you want it in production, you precompile it using a Grunt/Gulp task

Comment: @vitaly-t In addition, if you don't want to use a build system, you can just implement that pre-processing as a standalone JS file and execute it with node (i.e. `node yourfile.js`)...

Comment: If you track each processed file and process it only when loaded for the first time, there won't be any performance implication. And the issue with an extra setup is it is difficult to extend: if you want to support multiple syntax across multiple modules, generating build setups for them is a messy affair.

Comment: @vitaly-t the same code you may write for a run-time processing would be the same for build-time processing...and about the setup across modules, you can implement that task using convention over configuration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration

Comment: That's precisely my point, only we look at it differently: I see the simplest way in that simply loading a processing module would be sufficient to process the syntax it supports, without the necessity of an extra setup. Wouldn't that be sweet? :)

Comment: @vitaly-t Yes, but the issue is that it's not the right approach, I'm very sure about that. When you require a file you don't want to process it, but you just want to load it *as is*...

Comment: It may have some caveats, but I want to evaluate all options first, hence my question about whether or not it is possible, and if yes - then how.

Comment: @vitaly-t Actually you can intercept any call to `require` if you define a `require` function which calls NodeJS' one... BTW it's ugly :( I'll leave my answer here unless someone may provide you what you're looking for. My bet is you'll end up going with the build-time approach, don't be lazy!! :D it's 10-20 code lines far from you...............!!